# Classes and Subclasses c++

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I am new to C++ and I have to create a class vehicle so

```
class Vehicle:
private:

public: 
void Move(double);
void Stop;
void Turn(double);
```

Then I have to create 3 subclasses of car, bike and roller-skates, I don't know what to put in the header and cpp files for these classes any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot on on friendship and inheritance on following link

> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

You should do something like this:

```
#import "Vehicle.h"

class Car : public Vehicle {
  public:
   // Car specific methods
}
```